# Problem with a searching users in a search Fragment androidStudio & Firebase

Tags: android, firebase

I'm trying to do a basic social app but the search Fragment which is in the main activity makes the application crash with the error code : "java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.String.equals(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference"

The message says that i'm trying to do a if() statement on a null object which is not supposed to be. The error is at the if at the end of the following code:

```
@Override
 public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final ViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {
    firebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

    final UserObject user = mUsers.get(position);

    viewHolder.username.setText(user.getUsername());
    Glide.with(context).load(user.getImageurl()).into(viewHolder.image_profile);
    isFollowing(user.getId(), viewHolder.follow);

    if(user.getId().equals(firebaseUser.getUid())){
        viewHolder.follow.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

   This is suppose to hide a follow button when the user object has the 
   user id.

 for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                    User user = snapshot.getValue(User.class);
                    mUsers.add(user);
                }
```

Comment: `user.getId()` is returning null value, please check.

Comment: Can you explain please I dont get it @Astha

Comment: If you try to log `user.getId()`, prints the correct id? Please also add your database structure and responde with @AlexMamo

Comment: @Raphael- as your log says, you are trying to call `equals` on null object, meaning the id stored in your user is null. Actually id in your `mUsers` list is null.

Comment: Ok so I did the print and it print the id of the first user in my realtime databse BUT I realised that in the logcat it was written that the email and imageurl were not set and so they were null but nothing written about the id or username . for(DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                    UserObject user = snapshot.getValue(UserObject.class);
                    mUsers.add(user);
                } This is the function that create a new object for the recycler view in the searchFragment @AlexMamo

Comment: Please add that code to your question and please also add your database structure.

Comment: What do you mean by database structure ? @AlexMamo

Comment: A snippet of your JSON file or at least a screenshpt from the Firebase console.